# Prove the function $u(x):=1-|x|^{2-N}$ is in $W^{2,p}$ on $\{x\in \mathbb R^N;\,\,|x|>1\}$

Tags: real-analysis, sobolev-spaces

This is exercise 10.11 from Leoni's book.

Take $\Omega:=\{x\in  \mathbb R^N;\,\,|x|>1\}$ and let 
$$u(x):=1-|x|^{2-N}$$
 for $N\geq 3$.

I am trying to prove that $\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x_i\partial x_j}\in L^{p}(\Omega)$ for all $1\leq p<\infty$. Clearly, I have
$$\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x_i\partial x_j} = (N-2)\frac{\delta_{ij}|x|^N-Nx_ix_j|x|^{N-2}}{|x|^{2N}} $$
Suppose $i\neq j$, I have
$$\int_{\Omega}\left|\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x_i\partial x_j}\right|^p\leq \int_\Omega \frac{1}{|x|^{Np}}dx = \int_1^\infty r^{-Np+N-1}dr$$
To have integration convergen, I need $-Np+N-1<-1$ which is $p>1$...

I have no idea about how to prove the case $p=1$.

Also, when $i=j$, I just don't know how to deal with
$$ (N-2)\frac{|x|^N-Nx_i^2|x|^{N-2}}{|x|^{2N}} $$

Any help is really welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exercise is incorrectly stated: the second derivatives of $u$ are in $L^p$ for $1<p<\infty$ (in fact, also for $p=\infty$), but not for $p=1$.

The case $i=j$ is not much different from $i\ne j$: just use the triangle inequality to estimate the derivative by $C|x|^{-N}$.

---

Remark: disregarding $1$, we have a function $|x|^{2-N}$, which is homogeneous of degree $2-N$. Each derivative of order $k$ is homogeneous of degree $2-N-k$. This is already enough to determine its degree of integrability. For a function $\phi$ homogeneous of degree $d$, the integral of $|\phi|^p$ over dyadic shell $2^m<|x| \le 2^{m+1}$ is $C 2^{mpd} 2^{mN}$, and the series $\sum_{m\ge 0} 2^{mpd} 2^{mN}$ converges iff $pd+N<0$.

Comment: Thx! I am trying to prove rigorously that $p=1$ is indeed diverge. Also, thx for the remark!

Comment: The remark at the end of my question should help with that. With $d=-N$ and $p=1$, the series is $C\sum_{m\ge 0} 2^0$.